# Invalid API Key Error while calling "Generate SAML Assertion" API

Tags: saml, onelogin

Although depreciated, I can still call "Delegated Auth" API described here: 
https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/v1-v3/delegated-auth/delegate-authentication

with an API key without any issue. The API call returns success for valid users.

However, the same API key, when used with "Generate SAML Assertion" API described here:
https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/v1-v3/saml-assertions/generate-saml-assertion

returns

```
<error>
  <message>API key is invalid or missing</message>
  <code>invalid_or_missing_api_key</code>
</error>
```

I've collected app id from the url you are re-directed to when you click on the app after logging in to onelogin from a browser.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you calling the two APIs in the same manner? One thing to note is that one API takes the key as a query parameter and the other requires it in the body (part of the reason these APIs are deprecated is that they weren't very consistent)

If that's not the case, can you do us a favor and send details on the error you're getting to Devsupport@onelogin.com ?

If this is a bug our dev team will be able to investigate and (potentially) fix any issue.

Comment: Yes @JohnOffenhartz, "Delegated Auth" API was called as a GET request with params built into query string, and "Generate SAML Assertion" API was called as a POST request with params built into data as JSON object. I'll be emailing them with the issue and error message.